# Print one file per line using echo

Tags: bash, echo, bash-expansion

How can I print a list of files/directories one-per-line using `echo`?

I can replace spaces with newlines, but this doesn't work if the filenames contain spaces:

```
$ echo small*jpg
small1.jpg small2.jpg small photo 1.jpg small photo 2.jpg

$ echo small*jpg | tr ' ' '\n'
small1.jpg
small2.jpg
small
photo
1.jpg
small
photo
2.jpg
```

I know I can do this with `ls -d1`, but is it also possible using `echo`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data anyway, use `printf` instead](/q/65803) which is the POSIX replacement for the broken `echo` utility to output text.

```
printf '%s\n' small*jpg
```

You can also do:

```
printf '%s\0' small*jpg
```

to output the list in NUL delimited records (so it can be post-processed; for instance using GNU `xargs -r0`; remember that the newline character is as valid as space or any character in a filename).

Before POSIX came up with `printf`, ksh already had a `print` utility to replace `echo`. zsh copied it and added a `-l` option to print the arguments one per line:

```
print -rl -- small*jpg
```

ksh93 added a `-f` option to `print` for `printf` like printing. Copied by `zsh` as well, but not other ksh implementations:

```
print -f '%s\n' -- small*jpg
```

Note that all of those still print an empty line if not given any argument. A better `println` can be written as a function as:

```
println() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"
}
```

In `zsh`:

```
println() print -rC1 -- "$@"
```

Answer (score 3):

`echo` only uses spaces to separate the strings it receives as arguments.

Since your question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), here is what `help echo` in `bash` says (emphasis mine):

> Display the ARGs, **separated by a single space character** and followed by a newline, on the standard output.

Similar statements are found in the documentation for other implementations. E.g. that of [`echo` from `coreutils`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#echo-invocation), which you would likely find on GNU/Linux:

> `echo` writes each given string to standard output, with a space between each and a newline after the last one.

If you really want `echo` to print your file names on separate lines you have to feed them as a single string:

```
$ touch "small1.jpg" "small2.jpg" "small photo 1.jpg" "small photo 2.jpg"
$ (set -- small*.jpg; IFS='
'; echo "$*")
small1.jpg
small2.jpg
small photo 1.jpg
small photo 2.jpg
```

Here we are leveraging the behavior of the `*` special parameter: within double-quotes it expands to a *single word* in which the elements of the array of positional parameters are concatenated using the first character of the `IFS` variable (which we set to a newline).

The `(...)` syntax is used to execute the commands in a subshell environment—we generally don't want to affect the main one.

Note, however, that all `echo`'s limitations still apply, as mentioned in [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525404/315749), and therefore its use in this scenario is not advisable.

Comment: I strongly recommend setting `IFS` back to normal after anything like this.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Right, thank you. Answer amended.